# Is it possible to build a vue application without vue-cli?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, build

Like the titles says for itself. Is it possible to build a vue application with the help of webpack and without the vue cli?
If not, why? For my understanding vue-cli uses also webpack to build their files.

Comment: Check this tutorial for Vue v3 setup without vue-cli: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-vue-js-project-from-scratch-without-vue-cli/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course.

`vue-cli` uses webpack under-the-hood, but it abstracts away all the tedious webpack configuration with a sensible default so you can focus on just writing your application.

If you need to alter the way your application is built, for example you want to compress image assets, then unless `vue-cli` provides a config option for your specific need then you will have to alter the webpack configuration in some way (e.g. adding a new loader or altering the configuration of an existing loader, etc). `vue-cli` does expose some ways to do this, but you don't have full control over the webpack build from the beginning.

I usually have very specific requirements for how I want my web apps to be built, so I opt for the DIY webpack solution so that I have full control over all aspects of the build.

If you don't want to use `vue-cli` but still want to use webpack, then at minimum I would suggest the following packages:

- `webpack`
- `vue`
- `vue-loader` for compiling and bundling `.vue` single file components
- `babel-loader` for transpiling JavaScript
- `file-loader` for image assets
- `style-loader` for injecting styles into the DOM at runtime
- `css-loader` for loading modules referenced in CSS files like images and fonts

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Vue 3 without the Vue CLI in an existing application that has a custom Webpack configuration, and the following steps worked for me:

Install Vue3:

```
npm install --save vue@next
```

Install `vue-loader` (v16 or newer) and the new template compiler:

```
npm install --save-dev vue-loader@^16 @vue/compiler-sfc
```

Webpack Config:

```
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader'); // load plugin

//...

module: {
  rules: [
    {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'vue-loader' }
        ]
      }
  ]
},

plugins: [
  new VueLoaderPlugin()
]
```

Thanks to [Webpack for Vue 3](https://lmiller1990.github.io/electic/posts/20200406_webpack_for_vue_3.html) for the tip on installing the compiler without the CLI; I couldn't find that in the Vue 3 documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any build tools at all if you're willing to work within the limitations of browser-supported JavaScript. The [onboarding guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) doesn't use vue-cli, webpack or even Node at all.

My first nontrivial Vue app did use webpack, but not vue-cli. It was hand-configured based on advice from a then-current how-to.

Vue-cli is convenient to get a build process up and running quickly, but it's optimized for people who are either very comfortable with node build tools, or don't want to mess with the defaults very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is very possible...in fact, until recently, a lot of projects were built without that!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can add Vue functionality to existing project without Vue CLI.
Preferably a project using Webpack as bundler...then it is pretty simple.

You need 3 packages: vue@next, @vue/compiler-sfc and vue-loader and add some rule configuration in your webpack.config.js file.

Note! At writing moment you can not choose latest official vue-loader as it is still dependent on vue-template-compiler (used in Vue 2). You need to force in installation of v16+ (I use vue-loader 16.8.3) together with latest Vue v.3 (3.2.28)...

[Here](https://gist.github.com/CMQNordic/3a40aaa970dbddf48f23c44384162739#install-vue-from-html-or-npm) you can read detail description how do do it.

Answer (score -1):

yes vue-cli include webpack to build assets. Now, vue.js does the same things. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/package.json here is the package.json of Vue.js and you can see webpack is required.

So by default webpack is included into Vue.js

Answer (score -4):

## September 2022 Update

Use [create-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue).

```
npm init vue@latest project-name
```

or in your current directory

```
npm init vue@latest .
```