# Build typescript vue apps with only babel?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, babeljs

How can I transpile and build my typescript vue app with only babel? I used the vue-cli-service extensively but reached a point where I just need a minimal setup, without webpack or anything.

My .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["babel-preset-typescript-vue"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-typescript"]
}
```

My package.json dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-typescript-vue": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
},
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.2",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1"
}
```

My entry main.ts file:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(Vuex);
    
new Vue({render: h => h(App)}).$mount('#app');
```

My App.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
    import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component
    class App extends Vue {}

    export default App;
</script>
    
<template>
    <div class="foobar">Babel worked</div>
</template>
```

My build script:

```
babel src/main.ts --out-dir build
```

Comment: Do you use the `vue-cli3` to create your project?

Comment: @Tingsen Cheng yes in a matter of fact I do.

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103389/is-it-possible-to-build-a-vue-application-without-vue-cli

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot **build** with babel, as it only transpiles languages and it cannot build modules. You will still need some type of bundler to resolve `require / import` imports. If you don't want giant hefty webpack configs you can look at [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/)

If you want to actually just compile you `typescript` and `vue typescript` you need to install `@babel/preset-typescript` `@babel/preset-env`, include them in `.babelrc` file.

Then use `babel ./src/main.ts --out-dir build --extensions ".ts"` or better yet use locally installed babel `./node_modules/.bin/babel ./src/main.ts --out-dir build --extensions ".ts"`